# Firebase: Should Promise or Observable be used in an Angular project?

Tags: angular, facebook, firebase, promise, observable

I just started learning Angular. If I used Firebase for user authorization, then is it better to use `Promise` or `Observable`?

How would I need to change the URL, if when I try to log in via Facebook I get the error:

> Unable to load URL: The domain of this URL is not included in the list of application domains. To download this URL, add all the domains and subdomains of your application in the Domains field applications in your application settings.

Answer (score 1):

[RxJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs) is a more flexible and powerful framework than [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) for asynchronous programming. That being said, it is a matter of preference to use `Observables` or `Promises` when working with the Firebase APIs.

[**AngularFire**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) was developed to make it easier to integrate Firebase into Angular projects. The AngularFire API uses `Observables` rather than `Promises`, since RXJS is the de facto Angular asynchronous programming standard.

If you wanted to provide your own `RXJS` API for Firebase, one option would be to create an Angular service. The example below shows how you could wrap the Firebase function [`signInWithCustomToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#signinwithcustomtoken), which returns `Promise<UserCredential>`, and transform it to return `Observable<UserCredential>`.

### firebase-auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Optional } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'

import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirebaseAuthService {
  public app: firebase.app.App;
  public auth: firebase.auth.Auth;
  public user$: BehaviorSubject<firebase.User> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  // Note: FirebaseConfig is a class to enable injecting the Firebase app 
  // initialization params when providing the service in app.module.ts.
  constructor(@Optional() fb_config: FirebaseConfig, private http: HttpClient) {
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App
    this.app = firebase.initializeApp(fb_config);
    this.auth = firebase.auth(this.app);

    this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
      (user: firebase.User) => {
        if (user) {
          this.user$.next(user);
          console.log('User signed in');
        } else {
          this.user$.next(null);
          console.log('User signed out');
        }
      },
      (error: firebase.auth.Error) => {
        // handle error
      }
    )
  }

  public signInWithCustomToken(uid: string, secret_auth_code: string): 
      Observable<firebase.auth.UserCredential> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('uid', uid)
      .set('secret', secret_auth_code)
    return this.http.get('/get-custom-token', {params: params}).pipe(
      concatMap((json: any) => from(this.auth.signInWithCustomToken(json['custom_token'])))
    )
  }

  // ...
}
```

### Component

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService: FirebaseAuthService) {}
  // ...
}
```

### Template

```
<ng-container *ngIf="( authService.user$ | async ) as user">
  <div>Hello {{user.displayName}}</div>
</ng-container>
```